# Subquery with GROUPBY on calculated field: Your query does not include the specified expression '' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2013

I get the following error message

> "Your query does not include the specified expression 'SampleCode' as part of an aggregate function."

I've looked into aggregate functions and have tried various ways to GROUP BY using the individual data fields that make up the code but I can't seem to get anything to work.

'SampleCode' is a concatenated query field (query name: datqry_SampleNumber) that is based on data from 3 different tables to create a unique value as follows...

```
SampleCode: IIf([tbl_Carcass.SampleNumber]="-999","-999",
    "NPT-" & [tbl_SurveyInfo.SurveyYear*] & "-" & 
    [datqry_TransectData.Project_Code] & "-" & [tbl_Carcass.SampleNumber])
```

for SampleNumber values > 0001 (-999 is a placeholder indicating no SampleNumber assigned).  Note, SurveyYear* is a calculated field based on the SurveyDate data field.

So, since SampleCode needs to be unique to each sample, I am trying to build a duplicate query, based on the aforementioned query, to identify duplicate SampleCodes so they can be relabeled and archived w/ a unique qualifier.  The criteria for the duplicate query operation is as follows

```
In (SELECT [SampleCode] FROM [datqry_SampleNumber] As Tmp 
    GROUP BY [SampleCode] HAVING Count(*)>1 )
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?  Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Thx Rob!  The first set of code you provided to create qryDuplicates worked and is probably all I need to create a list to identify duplicate SampleCodes.  I will play w/ the other part to see how/if i can incorporate it into my final output query, but it may not be necessary; still fun and worth it to try.  Anyway, I can now continue moving forward, thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be a limitation of the JET engine used by Access to interpret its SQL.

It appears to be having trouble working with the [subquery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664.aspx) because it contains an aggregation of a calculated field (SampleCode in your case).

Try saving this as a separate query called, e.g. `qryDuplicates`:

```
SELECT [SampleCode] FROM [datqry_SampleNumber] 
    GROUP BY [SampleCode] HAVING Count(*)>1;
```

Then what you are trying to do will work as expected:

```
SELECT * from someTable WHERE someField IN (
    SELECT * FROM qryDuplicates
);
```

---

*TECHNICAL NOTE: I've tested it out and it is indeed specific to the fact that `SampleCode` is a calculated field. Doing exactly the same kind of grouped subquery works as expected when the field in question is not calculated.*

With [this test database](https://pastebin.com/PCFyjgeu) this query works:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Field3 IN (
    SELECT Field1 FROM datqry_SampleNumber 
    GROUP BY Field1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

And this doesn't

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Field3 IN (
    SELECT SampleCode FROM datqry_SampleNumber
    GROUP BY SampleCode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```